# O que significa << em Ruby?

Tags: ruby, operadores

Estou estudando um livro de lógica de programação e queria saber o que significa `<<`
veja em que o livro está aplicando:

> Essa sacada de manter uma variável de ajuda com o tamanho real
>   utilizado de um array é muito importante e extremamente usado em
>   diversas situações. Podemos remover nossa variável total_de_chutes e
>   usar o size :
>
> ```
> limite_de_tentativas = 5
>
> chutes = []
>
> for tentativa in 1..limite_de_tentativas
>
> chute = pede_um_numero chutes, tentativa,
>
> limite_de_tentativas
>
> chutes[chutes.size] = chute
>
> if verifica_se_acertou numero_secreto, chute
>
> break
>
> end
>
> end
> ```
>
> Mas se o Ruby tem algo para nos auxiliar com o tamanho atual de um
>   array, será que ele já não tem algo que nos ajuda a colocar um valor
>   no final dele? Sim, já vimos o símbolo << :
>
> ```
> chutes = [100, 300, 500]
>
> chutes << 600
>
> puts chutes.size # imprime 4
>
> puts chutes[3] # imprime 600
> ```
>
> Portanto, nosso código final fica ainda mais simples:
>
> ```
> da_boas_vindas
>
> numero_secreto = sorteia_numero_secreto
>
> limite_de_tentativas = 5
>
> chutes = []
>
> for tentativa in 1..limite_de_tentativas
>
> chute = pede_um_numero chutes, tentativa,
>
> limite_de_tentativas
>
> chutes << chute
>
> if verifica_se_acertou numero_secreto, chute
>
> break
>
> end
>
> end
> ```

Comment: Seja bem vindo rodolfo, enquanto uma resposta não chega, leie esta pergunta [What does << mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852072/what-does-mean-in-ruby) em inglês

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este é o `operador de concatenação`. Ele pode ser usado em contextos de coleções de dados. No exemplo mostrado ele está adicionando um item novo a um *array*.

Ele é a mesma coisa que escrever `array.concat(item)` que faz o que está na variável `array` tenha um item novo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Ruby/Conceptual.md).